# custom search form for custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, search, forms

I am creating a car dealership theme. I have a custom post with the name Car_posts. This custom post has the following fields. Make , Model, Year, Mileage, Condition, Minimum Price, Maximum Price etc. What I want is to create a custom search form by using the these fields: Make , Model, Min-Price, Max-Price and display the result in a page called search-results.php.This is my form:

```
          <form role="search" action="<?php echo site_url( '/' ); ?>" method="get" id="searchform">
            <input type="text" name="make" placeholder="Make"/>
            <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model"/>
            <input type="text" name="min_price" placeholder="Min Price"/>
            <input type="text" name="max_price" placeholder="max Price"/>

            <input type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
          </form>
```

This is my code

```
$meta_query = array();
if (!empty($make)) {
$meta_query[] = array(
     'key' => 'make',
     'value' => $make ,
     'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
}

if (!empty($make)) {
$meta_query[] = array(
     'key' => 'model',
     'value' => $model ,
     'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
}


$args=array(
    'post_type'=>'car_post',
    'relation'=>'AND',
    'meta_query'=>$meta_query
);

$the_loop = new WP_Query( $args ); if ( $the_loop->have_posts() ) : while (   $the_loop->have_posts() ) : $the_loop->the_post();

?>

<div>
    Search results here
</div
```

Please can someone help me the wordpress code for creating a working custom search form based on the above mentioned customd fields

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: You're going to have to write custom SQL that searches those fields. To point you in the right direction - https://adambalee.com/search-wordpress-by-custom-fields-without-a-plugin/

Comment: There is no need for custom SQL

Comment: Try add meta value in '"$make'" like this.